# Пунктуация в разговорной речи

Tags: пунктуация, разговорная-речь

Вопрос по оформлению разговорной речи. Например: "Я не понимаю(,) как, ну как он это делает?" Понятно, что подчинительная часть, состоящая из одного слова, не отделяется, но тут всё как-то мутно. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая нужна без вопросов.
Я не вижу здесь подчинительной части из одного слова. "как, ну как он это делает" - это одна "часть" с усилением в виде рефрена "как".

Comment: А если немного изменить: "Я не понимаю как [именно], но как он это делает!" (что-то вроде как эффектно). Здесь вроде бы не нужна запятая, верно?

Comment: Не нужна. Но здесь и синтаксис другой. Превое "как" и последующее "но как..." выступают либо в роли однородных членов (маловероятно, поскольку противопоставление налицо), либо это вообще разные "каки". В этом случае второе "как" более напоминает усилиткельную частицу - и таким образом подчинительной связи вообще нет: *"Я не понимаю как (=каким образом), но как (=насколько) эффектно он это делает"*. Последнее вернее всего.

Comment: Согласна. Первое "как" - наречие, второе - восклицательная частица

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тоже поставила запятую. Здесь полноценное придаточное (*как он это делает*). Просто в нем есть повтор слова "как" для акцентирования внимания именно на это слове.

Comment: синхрон)))

Comment: Бывает....

Comment: Во-первых, где во-вторых? Во-вторых, здесь получаются однородные союзы, что ли?

Comment: Во-вторых - см. во-первых.

Comment: Убираю во-первых. Слово как здесь не союз, а наречие.